# Only select the internal vertices of a subdivided plane

Tags: geometry-nodes

Im' trying to keep the edge vertices at one level and the internal vertices at another[image: Plane and nodeTree].
However, the Edge Neighbors, doesn't pick up on the vertex with 4 edges.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the *Edge Neighbors* node, so geometry nodes doesn't look at the vertices, it looks at the edges and interpolates the results of the comparison on the point domain, because ultimately *Set Position* operates on points. That's the reason your central point here sticks out : two of the edges it's attached to are interior edges that have two faces attached. The two other edges it's attached to are border edges that have just one face attached. The point inherits the average of [2,2,1,1] which is 1,5. The comparison operator does its job and selects that point because it is not equal to 1, and the point is displaced.

In order to discriminate the border points from the interior points, you can use the *Vertex Neighbors* node and specifically its output *Face Count*.

[image]

To gain a better understanding of how attributes are interpolated over a mesh, I suggest reading this : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html

And particularly this part :

> Normally, domain conversions use simple averages for values, but
> Boolean data type attributes have special rules for interpolation
> (...)

Answer (score 1):

I found it! [image]
I was missing the Evaluate on Domain node for edges and now it works.